# How can I put a star frame around this diamond?

Tags: c

I need to put a star frame around this diamond. The output should be like this. This is an example for input '9'.

```
     *
    *.*
   *. .*
  *. . .*
 *. . . .*
*. . . . .*
 *. . . .*
  *. . .*
   *. .*
    *.*
     *
```

Here is the code without the frame:

```
int main()
{
    int d = 0;
    scanf("%d", &d);
    int d2 = (d / 2) + 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= d2;i++)
    {
        for(int c = 1; c<=d2-i;c++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(int j = 0;j < i;j++)
        {
            printf(".");
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(int i = d2-1; i >= 1;i--)
    {
        for(int c = 1; c<=d2-i;c++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(int j = i;j > 0;j--)
        {
            printf(".");
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This is the output for the code without the frame:

```
    .
   . .
  . . .
 . . . .
. . . . .
 . . . .
  . . .
   . .
    .
```

And this is the code I wrote for the frame put it isn't working properly. The spaces aren't correctly printed and the dots aren't correct as well. I couldn't fix it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int d = 0;
    scanf("%d", &d);
    int d2 = (d / 2) + 1;
    int s = 0;

    // Printing the upper half of the diamond and the frame
    for(int i = 1; i <= d2; i++)
    {
        for(int c = 1; c <= d2 - i; c++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        if (i > 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
            {
                printf(".");
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Printing the lower half of the diamond and the frame
    for(int i = d2 - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        for(int c = 1; c <= d2 - i; c++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        if (i > 1)
        {
            for (int j = i - 2; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                printf(".");
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The output for the code above is like this:

```
    *
   *. *
  *. . *
 *. . . *
*. . . . *
 *. . . *
  *. . *
   *. *
    *
```

Comment: What does the expected output look like without the frame? What is the current output? Kindly add that to your question.

Comment: @Harith Thank you for telling me. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner `for` loops, you unconditionally print a space after each `.`. You shouldn't do that in case it's the last `.` on the line. You could fix it by adding a check. It also helps with readability if you make the upper and lower loop use the same conditions.

It could look like this:

```c
for (int j = i - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
    putchar('.');
    if (j) putchar(' '); // don't print a space unless j>0
}
```

To make space for the frame, you could also add `2` to the inputted `n`.

```c
if(scanf("%d", &d) != 1) exit(1);
d += 2;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hGh73GPos)

Comment: Thank you this worked. But what about the diagram? I want the input 9 be the diagram of the dots in the diamond. Like the first output. And then the stars around it.

Comment: @Coder I added a solution for that too